# Parameter to disable Azkaban job by default

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, azkaban

Given the following Azkaban configuration that has 1 flow containing 3 jobs, how do I disable Job2 by default? Is there a parameter/configuration for that?

I know that I could go in the UI and disable the job manually. However, I'd like to have the Job2 disabled by default and possibly enable it from the UI only when needed.

```
hadoop {

  def input = "..."

  workflow('MyWorkflow') {

    hadoopJavaJob('Job1') {
      uses 'my.package.Job1Runner'

      reads files: [ ... ]
      writes files: [ ... ]
    }

    hadoopJavaJob('Job2') {
      uses 'my.package.Job2Runner'
      depends 'Job1'

      reads files: [ ... ]
      writes files: [ ... ]
    }

    hadoopJavaJob('Job3') {
      uses 'my.package.Job3Runner'
      depends 'Job2'

      reads files: [ ... ]
      writes files: [ ... ]
    }

    targets 'Job3'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional *disabled* parameter. See "Execute A Flow" section of the [documentation](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/).